# Pass javascript value into html <a href>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript variable `imgIndex` that I'd like to send to an `<a href="...">` so I can change the id based on `imgIndex`

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages($cat, $site)) ?>];
window.imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid ?>;

$(document).ready(function() {      

    var img = document.getElementById("showimg");
    img.src = imgArray[<?php echo $imgid ?>];

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        var rightarrow = 39;
        var leftarrow = 37;
        var random = 82;

        if (key == rightarrow) 
        {
            imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
        }
        if (key == leftarrow) 
        {
            if (imgIndex == 0) 
            {
                imgIndex = imgArray.length;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
        }
        if (key == random) 
        {
            imgIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*(imgArray.length-1))+1);
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
        }   

    });
});

</script>
```

**HTML:**
Then send `imgIndex` here so the id of the image will equal `imgIndex`:

```
<a href="?action=viewcomic&id=imgIndex"><img id="prevkey" src="./images/SiteDesign/prev.png" alt="Comic Navigation" /></a>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to pass it to `<a href="...">`?

**EDIT:**

The reason I can't use  is because I need to manipulate a javascript variable, not a number (as the browser renders the php value).

Comment: your question isn't clear. you should do your homework before posting a question.

Comment: you will need to show the code where the anchor `<a>` is generated.

Comment: Couldn't you just move the `<?php echo $imgid ?>` into the `href` of the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the target of the link after you are done processing `imgIndex`.

```
document.getElementById("yourLinkId").href = "?action=viewcomic&id=" + window.imgIndex;
```

Other than that, you can append an event handler to the link, which I am showing here as a sample for jQuery:

```
$("#yourLinkId").on("click", function()
{
    $(this).attr("href", "?action=viewcomic&id=" + window.imgIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, if you echo `imgIndex` into the `<a>` tag like so:

```
<a href="?action=viewcomic&id=<?php echo $imgid ?>"><img id="prevkey" src="./images/SiteDesign/prev.png" alt="Comic Navigation" /></a>
```

Then you can get the imgid from the querystring with:

```
<?php $imgid = $_GET["id"] ?>
```

Comment: I've updated my code as to why I can't use the php value directly

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the php variable in link? if you can, is the best solution.

```
<a href="?action=viewcomic&id=<?php echo $imgid; ?>"><img id="prevkey" src="./images/SiteDesign/prev.png" alt="Comic Navigation"/></a>
```

Comment: I've updated my code as to why I can't use the php value directly